# Orthogonal polynomial expansion and QR decomposition

Tags: r, polynomial, qr-decomposition

Here is the source code of `R` `poly` function (boundary checking are removed). Why we can use QR to build polynomial expansion, which is very different from orthogonal polynomial tutorials like [this one](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH304-503/Lect4-04web.pdf). Could anyone help me to understand the connection between these two?

```
xbar <- mean(x)
x <- x - xbar
X <- outer(x, 0L:degree, "^")
QR <- qr(X)

z <- QR$qr
z <- z * (row(z) == col(z))
Z <- qr.qy(QR, z)
norm2 <- colSums(Z^2)
alpha <- (colSums(x * Z^2)/norm2 + xbar)[1L:degree]
norm2 <- c(1, norm2)

Z <- Z/rep(sqrt(norm2[-1L]), each = length(x))
colnames(Z) <- 0L:degree
Z <- Z[, -1, drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Could you expand your question to be independent of the code presented? QR decomposition is equivalent to Gram Schmidt orthogonalization, in which case it builds a sequence of orthogonal polynomials that approximate your function with minimal least-squares error.

Comment: I think there is an interesting question here:  How is orthogonalization in a function space related to orthogonalization in of the projection of that space into $R^n$ induced by evaluation at a collection of data points.

Comment: Thanks @AlexR. I think Matt may be better to help me to expand my question. Basically I read what is QR decomposition from linear algebra book, and read what is orthogonal polynomial, but not quite understand why R can use such code to give me the answer for "orthogonal polynomial expansion". I am not able to explain clearly is because my knowledge is not sufficient to describe this in math and want some help to see the math behind these lines of R code.

Comment: @hxd1011 Is that what you were after?  Do you want me to take a shot at editing your question?

Comment: @MatthewDrury we discussed this question couple days ago, if you have time, could you please help me to revise the question?